# svg image before and after with svg image

Tags: css

I have a drop down that is only active if someone is logged in

this is my css code

```
.hasDropdown>a:after {
    content: "\e259";
    font-family: Glyphicons Halflings;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 13px;
    display: block;
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #e1b130;
}
.hasDropdown>a.isActive:after {
    content: "\e260";
}
```

The above works fine.. What I am trying to do is instead of using  font awesome I want to use an arrow svg image I have tried the following.

```
.hasDropdown>a:after {
        content: url(arrow.svg);
            position: absolute;
        top: 0px;
        right: 13px;
        display: block;
        color: #e1b130;
    }
```

but it doesn't show

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
.hasDropdown>a:after {
    background-image: url(arrow.svg);
    background-position: center center;
    background-size: cover;
    width: 40px;
    height:40px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0px;
    right: 13px;
    display: block;
    color: #e1b130;
}
```

Comment: maybe URL needs adjusting?